# all anchor tag's onclick function is called when click on one tag in vuejs and pug

Tags: vuejs2

i have 4 anchor tag with same onclick function, but when i click on one tag, all tag's onclick function is called

```
ul.menu-list 
   router-link(tag="li" to="/reports")
     a.has-text-white(:onclick='selectTab("reports")') Report
   router-link(tag="li" to="/adList")
     a.has-text-white(:onclick='selectTab("adSet")') AdSet
   router-link(tag="li" to="/adSetList")
     a.has-text-white(:onclick='selectTab("adSetList")') AdSetList
   router-link(tag="li" to="/sites")
     a.has-text-white(:onclick='selectTab("sites")') Sites
```

and onclick function is:

```
selectTab(tabName: string) {
    console.log(tabName);
}
```

So I want to know why when i click to Report, all of a tag's onclick function is called?

In this case, all of "report", "adSet", "adSetList", "sites" is logged

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is not right! It's not the vue events binding syntax.You need use `@click="selectTab('reports')"`
 or `v-on:click="selectTab('reports')"`; 
As for the logger ，it is beacause when a vue component is initing， it auto invoke the getter of dependent data to get dependences！

Answer (score 0):

If you put your ***click event*** on `router-link` and change the syntax a little bit that should work properly.You should change `:onclick` to `v-on:click` or `@click` and when using ***click event*** on `router-link` add ***.native*** to the event. Here is an example:

```js
const Home = {
    template: '<div id="home">Reports</div>'
}

const Component1 = {
    template: '<div id="component1">Adset</div>'
};

const Component2 = {
    template: '<div id="component2">Adsetlist</div>'
};
const Component3 = {
    template: '<div id="component3">sites</div>'
};

const routes = [
    { path: '/reports', component: Home },
    { path: '/adList', component: Component1 },
    { path: '/adSetList', component: Component2 },
    { path: '/sites', component: Component3 },
]

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  data: {
    
  },
  methods: {
    selectTab(tabName) {
       console.log(tabName);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-router/3.0.2/vue-router.min.js"></script>
<body class="text-center body">
  <div id="app">
     <ul class="menu-list">
       <router-link tag="li" to="/reports" v-on:click.native="selectTab('reports')">
         <a class="has-text-white">Report</a>
       </router-link>
       <router-link tag="li" to="/adList" v-on:click.native="selectTab('adSet')">
         <a class="has-text-white">AdSet</a>
       </router-link>
       <router-link tag="li" to="/adSetList" v-on:click.native="selectTab('adSetList')">
         <a class="has-text-white">AdSetList</a>
       </router-link>
       <router-link tag="li" to="/sites" v-on:click.native="selectTab('sites')">
         <a class="has-text-white">Sites</a>
       </router-link>
    </ul>
    
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</body>
```